# How to make a own input dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

So here is the problem, I want to make kind of a input dialog, that when a button in the main frame is clicked, it triggers the input dialog. And we can type words into the dialog, and then click the "Add" button on the input dialog so that the textbox on the main frame can display the string I just entered. However, I currently facing the difficulty to do this. Because the dialog and the main frame are two modules, which means that when I click the button on main frame to trigger the input dialog, it can't wait till I input the string, and the button event handler finish their job, so it can never read my input. Anyway, here is my code:

```
 /* some code */

 // add first name and last name
 private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Add add = new Add();   // declare a Add object
    add.Visible = true;    // show the Add frame
    if (add.isOK)
    {
        firstName = add.getFirstName();
        lastName = add.getLastName();
        textArea.Text = "First Name: " + firstName + "\r\n";    // textArea is a multiple line textbox
        textArea.Text += "Last Name: " + lastName;
    }
}

/* some code */
```

Above is the Add button on the main frame that trigger the Add object (the input dialog). And here is my Add class:

```
namespace DatabaseToAPI
{
    public partial class Add : Form
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        public bool isOK = false;  // to check if name is provided

        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Visible = false;  // only become visible when the main form's Add button is clicked
        }

        public string getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;  // return the first name
        }

        public string getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;   // return the last name
        }

        // Add button event handler
        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstNameBox.Text != "" && lastNameBox.Text != "")   // if name is provided
            {
                firstName = firstNameBox.Text;
                lastName = lastNameBox.Text;
                isOK = true;    // name has provided
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide both first name and last name", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }

        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
 }
```

As you can see, the Add class is basically like a input dialog, when the Add button is clicked on the main form, the Add form appears. The only problem is that the event handler for the input dialog trigger button on the main frame can't wait till I enter the name and click the button to signal I finish, it simply just go through the code without waiting the Add class finish their job. How can I do so that the main form knows when do I add the name so that they can read the text I put ?

Comment: Is the text `First Name:` & `Last Name:` appearing in the text box? Or is it just blank?

Comment: What seems to be wrong is you have two addButton_Click()...

Comment: Oh, I see - you're not actually showing `Add` as a dialog so the when the `if (add.isOK)` executes the `isOK` is `false`.

Comment: And what's with the Java method naming convention? :-p

Comment: Have you debugged the code to confirm that addButton_Click is being executed and that firstname and lastname have values?  The fact that you've got two addButton_Click methods looks suspicious to me.  Are both being executed as you expect?

Comment: You would have to replace `add.Visible = true;` with `add.ShowDialog();`

Comment: When you do add.getFirstName() and add.getLastName(), the add form is already closed.

Comment: Get rid of this.Close() from the Add form's addButton_Click(). See if that works. Change visibility or close from the parent form

Comment: I know what is wrong with my code. The addButton_click (in the main form) do its job without waiting the user to enter the string in the Add class. Because it is simply go over the code, nothing is stopping it to wait for the user to enter the string in the Add class form and click the button. Therefore, every time I trigger the dialog, isOK is always false; or even I don't put isOK boolean, it will still only read the blank textboxes.

Comment: There is no need to keep variables in the form for first/last name as the most up to date information is contained in the `TextBox.Text` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you call a modal dialog in `C#`

```
Add dlg = new Add();
if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    lastName = dlg.LastName;
    firstName = dlg.FirstName;
}
```

To do this you need to return `DialogResult.OK` when the form `Add` closes. So in the form you need

```
public partial class Add : Form
{
    public Add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult=DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public string FirstName { get { return textBox1.Text; } }
    public string LastName { get { return textBox2.Text; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general pattern about dialogs:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using(var add = new Add()) // so that it will be disposed after usage
   {
       if (add.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           firstName = add.getFirstName();
           lastName = add.getLastName();
           textArea.Text = "First Name: " + firstName + "\r\n";
           textArea.Text += "Last Name: " + lastName;
       }
   }
}
```

And in your dialog code, you should remove isOK and use DialogResult = DialogResult.OK / DialogResult.Cancel in relative button events.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to the people who answered, I succeeded. We basically just treat the form as a dialog. Here is the code:

```
// add first name and last name
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add add = new Add();
    add.ShowDialog(this);

    try {
        if (add.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            firstName = add.getFirstName();
            lastName = add.getLastName();
            textArea.Text = "First Name: " + firstName + "\r\n";
            textArea.Text += "Last Name: " + lastName;
        }
    } 
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the Add class:

```
namespace DatabaseToAPI
{
    public partial class Add : Form
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Visible = false;
        }

        public string getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public string getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (firstNameBox.Text != "" && lastNameBox.Text != "")
            {
                firstName = firstNameBox.Text;
                lastName = lastNameBox.Text;
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide both first name and last name", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }

        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: private variables `firstName` and `lastName` are superfluous.